# What is the purpose of setting a key in data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

I am using `data.table` and there are many functions which require me to set a key (e.g. `X[Y]`). As such, I wish to understand what a key does in order to properly set keys in my data tables.

---

One source I read was `?setkey`.

> `setkey()` sorts a `data.table` and marks it as sorted. The sorted columns are the key. The key can be any columns in any order. The columns are sorted in ascending order always. The table is changed by reference. No copy is made at all, other than temporary working memory as large as one column.

My takeaway here is that a key would "sort" the data.table, resulting in a very similar effect to `order()`. However, it doesn't explain the purpose of having a key.

---

The data.table FAQ 3.2 and 3.3 explains:

> 3.2 I don't have a key on a large table, but grouping is still really quick. Why is that?
>
> data.table uses radix sorting. This is signicantly faster than other
> sort algorithms. Radix is specically for integers only, see
> `?base::sort.list(x,method="radix")`. This is also one reason why
> `setkey()` is quick. When no key is set, or we group in a different order
> from that of the key, we call it an ad hoc by.
>
> 3.3 Why is grouping by columns in the key faster than an ad hoc by?
>
> Because each group is contiguous in RAM, thereby minimising page
> fetches, and memory can be copied in bulk (`memcpy` in C) rather than
> looping in C.

From here, I guess that setting a key somehow allows R to use "radix sorting" over other algorithms, and that's why it is faster.

---

The 10 minute quick start guide also has a guide on keys.

> 1. Keys
>
> Let's start by considering data.frame, specically rownames (or in
> English, row names). That is, the multiple names belonging to a single
> row. The multiple names belonging to the single row? That is not what
> we are used to in a data.frame. We know that each row has at most one
> name. A person has at least two names, a rst name and a second name.
> That is useful to organise a telephone directory, for example, which
> is sorted by surname, then rst name. However, each row in a
> data.frame can only have one name.
>
> A key consists of one or more
> columns of rownames, which may be integer, factor, character or some
> other class, not simply character. Furthermore, the rows are sorted by
> the key. Therefore, a data.table can have at most one key, because it
> cannot be sorted in more than one way.
>
> Uniqueness is not enforced,
> i.e., duplicate key values are allowed. Since the rows are sorted by
> the key, any duplicates in the key will appear consecutively

The telephone directory was helpful in understanding what a key is, but it seems that a key is no different when compared to having a factor column. Furthermore, it does not explain why is a key needed (especially to use certain functions) and how to choose the column to set as key. Also, it seems that in a data.table with time as a column, setting any other column as key would probably mess the time column too, which makes it even more confusing as I do not know if I am allowed set any other column as key. Can someone enlighten me please?

Comment: "I guess that setting a key somehow allows R to use "radix sorting" over other algorithms" --I don't get that from the help at all.  My read is that setting a key sorts by a key.  You can do "ad hoc" sorting by other columns than the key, and it's fast, but not as fast as if you had already sorted.

Comment: I think it's that binary search is faster than vector scan when selecting rows. I'm not a computer scientist, so I don't know what that actually means. Besides the FAQ, see [the introduction](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.pdf).

Answer (score 133, accepted):

In addition to this answer, please refer to the vignettes [Secondary indices and auto indexing](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-secondary-indices-and-auto-indexing.html) and [Keys and fast binary search based subset](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-keys-fast-subset.html) as well.

[This issue](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/944) highlights the other vignettes that we plan to.

---

I've updated this answer again (Feb 2016) in light of the new `on=` feature that allows *ad-hoc* joins as well. See history for earlier (outdated) answers.

#### What exactly does `setkey(DT, a, b)` do?

It does two things:

1. reorders the rows of the *data.table* `DT` by the column(s) provided (*a*, *b*) *by reference*, always in *increasing* order.
2. marks those columns as *key* columns by setting an attribute called `sorted` to `DT`.

The reordering is both fast (due to *data.table*'s internal radix sorting) and memory efficient (only one extra column of type *double* is allocated).

#### When is `setkey()` required?

For grouping operations, `setkey()` was never an absolute requirement. That is, we can perform a *cold-by* or *adhoc-by*.

```
## "cold" by
require(data.table)
DT <- data.table(x=rep(1:5, each=2), y=1:10)
DT[, mean(y), by=x] # no key is set, order of groups preserved in result
```

However, prior to `v1.9.6`, joins of the form `x[i]` required `key` to be set on `x`. **With the new `on=` argument from v1.9.6+**, this is not true anymore, and setting keys is therefore *not* an absolute requirement here as well.

```
## joins using < v1.9.6 
setkey(X, a) # absolutely required
setkey(Y, a) # not absolutely required as long as 'a' is the first column
X[Y]

## joins using v1.9.6+
X[Y, on="a"]
# or if the column names are x_a and y_a respectively
X[Y, on=c("x_a" = "y_a")]
```

Note that `on=` argument can be explicitly specified even for `keyed` joins as well.

> The only operation that requires `key` to be absolutely set is the [foverlaps()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25655497/559784) function. But we are working on some more features which when done would remove this requirement.

- **So what's the reason for implementing `on=` argument?**

  There are quite a few reasons.

  1. It allows to clearly distinguish the operation as an operation involving two *data.tables*. Just doing `X[Y]` does not distinguish this as well, although it could be clear by naming the variables appropriately.
  2. It also allows to understand the columns on which the *join/subset* is being performed immediately by looking at that line of code (and not having to traceback to the corresponding `setkey()` line).
  3. In operations where columns are added or updated *by reference*, `on=` operations are much more performant as it doesn't need the entire data.table to be reordered just to add/update column(s). For example,

     ```
      ## compare 
      setkey(X, a, b) # why physically reorder X to just add/update a column?
      X[Y, col := i.val]

      ## to
      X[Y, col := i.val, on=c("a", "b")]
     ```

     In the second case, we did not have to reorder. It's not computing the order that's time consuming, but physically reordering the data.table in RAM, and by avoiding it, we retain the original order, and it is also performant.
  4. Even otherwise, unless you're performing joins repetitively, there should be no noticeable performance difference between a *keyed* and *ad-hoc* joins.

This leads to the question, what advantage does keying a *data.table* have anymore?

- **Is there an advantage to keying a data.table?**

  Keying a *data.table* physically reorders it based on those column(s) in RAM. Computing the order is not usually the time consuming part, rather the *reordering* itself. However, once we've the data sorted in RAM, the rows belonging to the same group are all contiguous in RAM, and is therefore very cache efficient. It's the sortedness that speeds up operations on keyed data.tables.

  It is therefore essential to figure out if the time spent on reordering the entire data.table is worth the time to do a cache-efficient join/aggregation. Usually, unless there are repetitive grouping / join operations being performed on the same *keyed* data.table, there should not be a noticeable difference.

> In most cases therefore, there shouldn't be a need to set keys anymore. We recommend using `on=` wherever possible, unless setting key has a dramatic improvement in performance that you'd like to exploit.

**Question:** What do you think would be the performance like in comparison to a *keyed* join, if you use `setorder()` to reorder the *data.table* and use `on=`? If you've followed thus far, you should be able to figure it out :-).

Comment: Cool, thanks! Up until now, I hadn't thought about what "binary search" actually meant, nor really understood the reason why it was used instead of a hash.

Comment: @Arun, is `DT[J(1e4:1e5)]` really equivalent to `DF[DF$x > 1e4 & DF$x < 1e5, ]`? Could you point me to what `J` means? Also that search wouldn't return any rows since `sample(1e4, 1e7, TRUE)` does not include numbers above 1e4.

Comment: @fishtank, in this case, it should be `>=` and `<=` -- fixed. `J` (and `.`) are aliases to `list` (i.e., they are equivalent). Internally when `i` is a list, it's converted to a data.table following which binary search is used to compute row indices. Fixed `1e4` to `1e5` to avoid confusion. Thanks for spotting. Note that we can directly use `on=` argument now to perform binary subsets rather than setting key. Read more from the new [HTML vignettes](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started). And keep an eye on that page for vignettes for joins.

Comment: perhaps this could go for a more thorough update? the "when required" section seems outdated, e.g.

Comment: What function tells you the key being used?

Comment: Not sure if we share the same opinion regarding the answer to the question at the end. My reasoning: Even if the DT was sorted using setorder(), when we perform a join (later), the join algorithm does not know that the data is sorted already, thus has to go through all lines to be sure. If the join algorithm knows that the data is sorted (because of the $sorted attribute), it can save time.

Answer (score 23):

A key is basically an index into a dataset, which allows for very fast and efficient sort, filter, and join operations. These are probably the best reasons to use data tables instead of data frames (the syntax for using data tables is also much more user friendly, but that has nothing to do with keys).

If you don't understand indexes, consider this: a phone book is "indexed" by name. So if I want to look up someone's phone number, it's pretty straightforward. But suppose I want to search by phone number (e.g., look up who has a particular phone number)? Unless I can "re-index" the phone book by phone number, it will take a very long time.

Consider the following example: suppose I have a table, ZIP, of all the zip codes in the US (>33,000) along with associated information (city, state, population, median income, etc.). If I want to look up the information for a specific zip code, the search (filter) is about 1000 times faster if I `setkey(ZIP, zipcode)` first.

Another benefit has to do with joins. Suppose a have a list of people and their zip codes in a data table (call it "PPL"), and I want to append information from the ZIP table (e.g. city, state, and so on). The following code will do it:

```
setkey(ZIP, zipcode)
setkey(PPL, zipcode)
full.info <- PPL[ZIP, nomatch = FALSE]
```

This is a "join" in the sense that I'm joining the information from 2 tables based in a common field (zipcode). Joins like this on very large tables are extremely slow with data frames, and extremely fast with data tables. In a real-life example I had to do more than 20,000 joins like this on a full table of zip codes. With data tables the script took about 20 min. to run. I didn't even try it with data frames because it would have taken more than 2 weeks.

IMHO you should not just read but **study** the FAQ and Intro material. It's easier to grasp if you have an actual problem to apply this to.

[Response to @Frank's comment]

Re: **sorting vs. indexing** - Based on the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20076511/), it appears that `setkey(...)` does in fact rearrange the columns in the table (e.g., a physical sort), and does not create an index in the database sense. This has some practical implications: for one thing if you set the key in a table with `setkey(...)` and then change any of the values in the key column, data.table merely declares the table to be no longer sorted (by turning off the `sorted` attribute); it does **not** dynamically re-index to maintain the proper sort order (as would happen in a database). Also, "removing the key" using `setkey(DT, NULL)` does **not** restore the table to it's original, unsorted order.

Re: **filter vs. join** - the practical difference is that filtering extracts a subset from a single dataset, whereas join combines data from two datasets based on a common field. There are many different kinds of join (inner, outer, left). The example above is an inner join (only records with keys common to both tables are returned), and this does have many similarities to filtering.

Comment: +1. Regarding your first sentence... it's already sorted right? And isn't a join a special case of a filter (or an operation that takes filtering as its first step)? Seems like "better filtering" sums up the whole benefit.

Comment: Or better scanning I suppose.

Comment: @jlhoward Thanks. My prior belief was that sorting was not among the benefits of setting the key (since if you want to sort, you should just sort), and also that `setkey` actually does reorder the rows irreversibly. If it is only for display purposes, then how do I print the first ten rows according to the "true" ordering (that I would have seen prior to setkey)? I'm pretty sure `setkey(DT,NULL)` does not do this... (cont.)

Comment: ... (cont.) Also, I haven't looked at the code for the package, but to join `X[Y,...]`, you need to "filter" X's rows using the key. Granted, other stuff happens after that (Y's columns are made available, and there's an implicit by-without-by), but I still don't see that as a conceptually distinct benefit. I guess your answer is put in terms of operations you might want to do, though, where the distinction may be helpful.

Comment: @Frank - Actually `setkey(DT,NULL)` does remove any keys.

Comment: Um, I think you are confused about this part where you say "creates an index, without physically re-ordering the data in the table...for display purposes". @Arun seems to be saying that there is no index or hash and (as far as I can tell) there is nothing special happening just for display purposes as a result of setkey. Consider `DT<- data.table(a=3:1)`. Its single column is decreasing, right? If you run `setkey(DT,a);setkey(DT,NULL)`, can you guess what order that column is in?

Comment: @Frank - So `setkey(DT,NULL)` removes the key but does not affect sort order. Posed a question about this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20076511/). Let's see.

Comment: Nice, well-posed question there! In light of the answer, maybe you want to edit your answer here (which is useful) in the part where you talk about it ("creates and index", etc.).