# data.table - does setkey(...) create an index or physically reorder the rows in a data table?

Tags: r, data.table

This (very basic) question is the result of an exchange [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20039335/).

The documentation for `setkey()` states:

> setkey() sorts a data.table and marks it as sorted. The sorted columns
>   are the key. The key can be any columns in any order. The columns are
>   sorted in ascending order always. The table is **changed by
>   reference**...  (emphasis added)

I have always interpreted this to mean that `setkey()` creates an index, rather than physically rearranging the rows of the data table (similar to indexing a database table). But if this was true then removing the key (using `setkey(DT,NULL)`), should remove the index and restore the data table to it's original, unsorted order. This is not what happens:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(a=3:1, b=1:3, c=5:7); DT
   a b c
1: 3 1 5
2: 2 2 6
3: 1 3 7
setkey(DT,a); DT
   a b c
1: 1 3 7
2: 2 2 6
3: 3 1 5
setkey(DT,NULL)
   a b c
1: 1 3 7
2: 2 2 6
3: 3 1 5
```

So two questions:

1: If the rows are rearranged (sorted), then what does "changed by reference" mean?

2: What does `setkey(DT,NULL)` do exactly?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but keep in mind that just because the table is _displayed_ as sorted does not mean that it was sorted when you set the key. Typing `DT` at the console is essentially the same as calling  a print function, and that function might be doing the sorting.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. The rows are sorted. "Changed by reference" here means there is no copying of the entire table and rows are just swapped.
2. `setkey(DT, NULL)` is equivalent to `setattr(DT, "sorted", NULL)`. It simply unsets the "sorted" attribute.

Comment: In addition, note that `dput(DT)` has actually changed in addition to getting a `sorted` attribute in the second example.