# rbind `data.tables` and preserve key

Tags: r, indexing, data.table

I'm looking for behavior similar to inserting into an already keyed SQL table, where the new rows added are inserted into existing keys.  For example, in this case:

```
dt <- data.table(a=1:10)
setkey(dt, a)
tables()
#      NAME NROW MB COLS KEY
# [1,] dt     10 1  a    a  
dt.2 <- rbindlist(list(dt, data.table(a=1:5)))
tables()
#      NAME NROW MB COLS KEY
# [1,] dt     10 1  a    a  
# [2,] dt.2   15 1  a
```

i would like to have the option of having `dt.2` "inherit" the key (updated with the incremental data, obviously) from `dt`, instead of having no key as actually happened.

I was at first a bit surprised at the loss of the key in the first place, but that is clearly the documented behavior.

Is there a clean way of doing this without calling `setkey` after each `rbind`/`rbindlist`?

Comment: the result of your `rbind` is unsorted, so you can't avoid calling `setkey` (had it been sorted you could shave off potentially a lot of time by setting the "sorted" attribute directly)

Comment: @eddi, understood, this is mostly a syntactic question.  It seems providing the option for the re-creating of they key from within the `rbind`/`rbindlist` would be reasonable given this is the default SQL behavior.  Aside: I'm assuming that if `dt` is very large and sorted, `setkey` will take advantage of that when creating the `dt.2` key, if not then there is definitely more than just a syntax issue here.

Comment: I guess a slightly different way of phrasing my last point, the result of by `rbind` is only partially unsorted, the first portion (in my use case, the large one) should already be sorted as per original key.

Comment: Setting a key in a data table is not the same as creating an index in a database table. See [this question](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/20076511/).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Essentially, `data.table` doesn't currently support row insert at all, let alone into a keyed table.  `rbind` creates a new `data.table` so isn't fast or memory efficient.

A similar question is here :

[How to delete a row by reference in data.table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10790204/how-to-delete-a-row-by-reference-in-r-data-table)

Currently, the typical workflow is to load files from disk using `fread` and `rbindlist` them together, or load data from a database using RODBC or similar.

We'd like to add fast row insert, but it isn't done yet.

Comment: is there a road map for `data.table` someplace?  I looked but didn't see one.

Comment: @BrodieG The closest to a public road map is the [feature request](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/?atid=978&group_id=240&func=browse) list which is ordered by 5 levels of priority (5 is top).