# Is there a more efficient algorithm to search

Tags: r, algorithm

I am trying to merge two datasets together in R based on two criteria. They have to have the same id and year. One of the vector has the size of about 10000 and the other 2000. I think if I do a two level one by one search, the computing time would explode. The data is sorted by id and year. Is there a more efficient search algorithm than the naive comparison ?

Comment: Yes. It's sorted by id and year. I have edited the question.

Comment: Note that 10k and 2k is relatively small numbers for a computer. So, here `explode` means about...1ms or something (extremely relative of course, but you get my point)? Since it's sorted you can skip ahead when things don't match.

Comment: Have you tried `merge`?

Comment: There are 4 vectors. two year and two id vectors. So there would be 2000^10000*2 comparions. I am not sure if I am thinking this problem correctly.

Comment: I think there is a problem with your reasoning here. You should be able to solve this in linear time by using hash tables or linear-time merge

Comment: Well, post some sample from each dataset so we can see better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many solutions to this problem, e.g. by merge, by indexing, by looping (as you said).

However, the most elegant solution is by using the `data.table` package, which is really fast for managing data sets, and can be considered an evolved version of `data.frame`.

Let us first set up the data: Based on the limited information that you have provided in the question, here is a dummy attempt to solve the problem.

```
install.packages("data.table")

library(data.table) 

set.seed(100)
dt1 <- data.table(
  id = 1:10000, 
  Year = sample(1950:2014,size=10000,replace = TRUE), 
  v1 = runif(10000)
  )
head(dt1)

dt2 <- data.table(
  id = sample(1:10000,2000), 
  Year = sample(1950:2014,size=2000,replace = TRUE), 
  v2 = runif(2000),
  v3 = runif(2000)
)
head(dt2)
```

Once data is set up, remaining part is very simple.

Step1: Set the keys.

```
setkey(dt1,id,Year)  # Set keys in first table
setkey(dt2,id,Year)  # Set keys in second table
```

Step2: Merge which ever way you want.

```
dt1[dt2,nomatch=0]
dt2[dt1,nomatch=0]
```

The time taken to merge the data is about 0.02 second. This works extremely fast for very large data-sets as well.

```
system.time(dt1[dt2,nomatch=0])    # 0.02 sec
system.time(dt2[dt1,nomatch=0])    # 0.02 sec
```

To learn more about data.table

```
?example(data.table)
```

Hope this helps!!

If not, plz post more details!!

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the data.table package. I find this intro to data.frame helpfu. Apparently, data.table uses binary search instead of vector scan. So it's much faster. [link](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.pdf)

Comment: Exactly. There are two others nice reads as well. Try: `vignette("datatable-faq")` and 
`vignette("datatable-timings")`

Comment: @YanSong, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20057411/559784) may help answer some questions about `data.table` and binary search.

Comment: @Shambho, +1. Like the definition "evolved version of data.frame" ;)

Comment: @Shambho, yes, thanks to Matt :). I just tagged along recently.