# R: scan vectors once instead of 4 times?

Tags: r

Suppose I have two equal length logical vectors.
Computing the [confusion matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix) the easy way:

```
c(sum(actual == 1 & predicted == 1),
  sum(actual == 0 & predicted == 1),
  sum(actual == 1 & predicted == 0),
  sum(actual == 0 & predicted == 0))
```

requires scanning the vectors **4** times.

Is it possible to do that in a single pass?

PS. I tried `table(2*actual+predicted)` and `table(actual,predicted)` but both are obviously much slower.

PPS. Speed is not my main consideration here, I am more interested in understanding the language.

Comment: Perhaps you could try `data.table`. ie. `DT <- data.table(actual, predicted);  setkey(DT, actual, predicted)[,.N, .(actual, predicted)]$N`

Comment: this is indeed faster! I guess data.table uses radix sort?

Comment: May be this link helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20039335/what-is-the-purpose-of-setting-a-key-in-data-table

Comment: @akrun: please turn your comment into an answer

Comment: Not as fast as `data.table` might be, but not too shabby either  `data_frame(actual, predicted) %>% group_by(actual, predicted) %>% summarise(n())`

Comment: @Khashaa: `Error: could not find function "%>%"`

Comment: You need `dplyr` to run this.  `install.packages("dplyr"); library(dplyr)`

Comment: You can also use dplyr's `count` function if you want to know the group sizes: `data_frame(actual, predicted) %>% count(actual, predicted)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this:

```
tabulate(4 - actual - 2*predicted, 4)
```

(`tabulate` here is much faster than `table` because it knows the output will be a vector of length 4).

Answer (score 6):

You could try using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(actual, predicted)
setkey(DT, actual, predicted)[,.N, .(actual, predicted)]$N
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
actual <- sample(0:1, 10 , replace=TRUE)
predicted <- sample(0:1, 10, replace=TRUE)
```

#### Benchmarks

Using `data.table_1.9.5` and `dplyr_0.4.0`

```
library(microbenchmark)
set.seed(245)
actual <- sample(0:1, 1e6 , replace=TRUE)
predicted <- sample(0:1, 1e6, replace=TRUE)
f1 <- function(){
  DT <- data.table(actual, predicted)
  setkey(DT, actual, predicted)[,.N, .(actual, predicted)]$N}

f2 <- function(){table(actual, predicted)}
f3 <- function() {data_frame(actual, predicted) %>%
                      group_by(actual, predicted) %>% 
                      summarise(n())}

microbenchmark(f1(), f2(), f3(), unit='relative', times=20L)
#Unit: relative
# expr       min        lq      mean   median        uq       max neval cld
#f1()  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.00000  1.000000  1.000000    20  a 
#f2() 20.818410 22.378995 22.321816 22.56931 22.140855 22.984667    20   b
#f3()  1.262047  1.248396  1.436559  1.21237  1.220109  2.504662    20  a
```

Including the `count` from `dplyr` and `tabulate` also in the benchmarks on a slightly bigger dataset

```
set.seed(498)
actual <- sample(0:1, 1e7 , replace=TRUE)
predicted <- sample(0:1, 1e7, replace=TRUE)
f4 <- function() {data_frame(actual, predicted) %>% 
                       count(actual, predicted)}
f5 <- function(){tabulate(4-actual-2*predicted, 4)}
```

#### Update

Including another `data.table` solution (provided by @Arun) also in the benchmarks

```
f6 <- function() {setDT(list(actual, predicted))[,.N, keyby=.(V1,V2)]$N}

microbenchmark(f1(),  f3(), f4(), f5(), f6(),  unit='relative', times=20L)
#Unit: relative
#expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval  cld
#f1() 2.003088 1.974501 2.020091 2.015193 2.080961 1.924808    20   c 
#f3() 2.488526 2.486019 2.450749 2.464082 2.481432 2.141309    20    d
#f4() 2.388386 2.423604 2.430581 2.459973 2.531792 2.191576    20    d
#f5() 1.034442 1.125585 1.192534 1.217337 1.239453 1.294920    20  b  
#f6() 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000    20 a
```

Comment: How does this compare with `plyr::count` or the `dplyr` solution suggested by Khashaa?

Comment: how about `tabulate` from @flodel's solution?

Comment: @sds Looks like it is faster because it doesn't need the conversion to `data.table/data.frame` along with `grouping`.

Comment: The data.table solution could be just: `setDT(list(actual, predicted))[,.N, keyby=.(V1,V2)]$N`.

Comment: @Arun Thanks for the comment.  I will include that in the benchmarks.

Answer (score 2):

There is `table` which computes a cross tabulation and should give similar results if `actual` and `predicted` contain only zeros and ones:

```
table(actual, predicted)
```

Internally, this works by `paste`ing the vectors -- horribly inefficient. It seems that the coercion to `character` also happens when tabulating only one value, and this might be the very reason for the bad performance also of `table(actual*2 + predicted)`.

Comment: still slow.  Is this the best I can hope for?

Comment: @sds: How long are your vectors? What do they contain?

Comment: logical vectors of length 3135417