# Reverse order for data.table `setkey()`

Tags: r, data.table, reverse

What is the optimal way to `setkey` the data.table with reversed order of the records? So far I use the combination of `setkey()` and `setorder()`:

```
setkeyrev <- function(inputDT,...){
  setkey(inputDT, ...)
  setorderv(inputDT, key(inputDT), order = -1)
  invisible(inputDT)
}
```

Is there a better solution?

UPD. here is an example:

```
myDT <- fread('
colA colB
1 b1
3 b3
8 b8
5 b5')

setkey(myDT, colA)
myDT

setkeyrev(myDT, colA)
myDT
```

Comment: Maybe `setkeyv(dt, rev(key(dt)))`?

Comment: I meant order of the records, not columns (it can be just one column).

Comment: Do you mean set the keys with descending sort?

Comment: yes! I will add an example to make it more clear

Comment: LGTM. What problems are you encountering with the current approach? Probably just remove the semi-colons.

Comment: Your way seems fine to me.

Comment: I didn't really encounter any problems, was just wondering if there is any shorter/nicer way. Thank you for confirming!

Comment: Oh, by the way, the end result does *not* have a key (though I guess you know this) -- it breaks when you reorder. Keys are only supported when data is in ascending order in memory, is my understanding.

Comment: ouch, I did not notice that, thank you for pointing out! If I understand correctly, there is no solution for this particular issue except creating new key column.

Comment: Yeah. These days, I only use keys for more convenient syntax (so I can skip writing `on=` during joins with tables where the key can easily be guessed, like my "eventDT" will be keyed by "event_id"). You might want to read the latest version of the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20057411/

Comment: ok, got it! Very useful reading.

Answer (score 1):

I am 3 years late but this may help someone else.  I was looking for a solution to this exact question, but as noted in the comments the the example in the OP doesn't preserve the keys.  The comments made me think of a simple solution. Create a new column giving the desired ordering (reverse rank), then use it as the key...

```
myDT <- fread('
colA colB
1 b1
3 b3
8 b8
5 b5')

myDT[,revorder:=frankv(colA,order=-1,ties.method = "first")]
setkey(myDT,revorder)
```

If you need reverse ordering within groups (like I did)...

```
myDT <- fread('
colA grp 
1 a
2 a
3 a
4 b
8 b
5 b')

myDT[,revorder:=frankv(colA,order=-1,ties.method = "first"),by = grp]
setkey(myDT,grp,revorder)
```