# R data.table - simple way to join on all columns without specifying column names

Tags: r, join, data.table

I have two tables A1 and A2 that I would like to join on all columns (purpose is to have a function that can be used to track changes to the data). Is there a easy way to join on all columns without specifying them explicitly.

Something like `A1[A2, on="ALL"]`

If anyone needs some code example I can provide it, but the question is more generally about if I have missed something in the help section for data.table.

I'm looking for a data.table solution. If there is none I'll use dplyr's:

```
inner_join(A1, A2, by = NULL)
```

Comment: Could you use something like `mget(intersect(names(A1), names(A2)))`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the way to do this in the data table is the following:

```
require(data.table)
dt1 <- data.table(A1 = c(1,2,3), A2 = c("A", "B", "D"))
dt2 <- data.table(A1 = c(3,2,3), A2 = c("A", "B", "C"))

setkeyv(dt1, names(dt1))
setkeyv(dt2, names(dt2))
```

and the inner join on all common columns is:

```
dt1[dt2, nomatch = 0]
```

---

Other options include the following (credits to Frank in the comments):

`dt1[dt2, on=names(dt2), nomatch = 0`]

This has the benefit of not requiring to key the data table. (More info can be found here: [What is the purpose of setting a key in data.table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20039335/what-is-the-purpose-of-setting-a-key-in-data-table/20057411#20057411) )

---

Another option using the data sets operations (available in version 1.9.7 or later):

```
fintersect(dt1, dt2)
```

Comment: These days, it's recommended to use `on=` instead of setting keys: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20057411/ so `dt1[dt2, on=names(dt2), nomatch = 0]`. Also, in the current devel version there are set operators for data sets, so `fintersect(dt1, dt2)` is now an option.

Comment: Didn't know! Thank you very much I will keep it in mind :) (And add it to the answer if you don't mind)

Comment: Sorry, didn't see the edit to your comment before. The `intersect` from the question you linked is different from the "fast" `fintersect` I was talking about and is only relevant for vectors, not tables of data.

Comment: up to date manual for [`fintersect`](http://jangorecki.gitlab.io/data.table/library/data.table/html/setops.html). When joining on all columns be aware that joining on double column type is not a best idea due to floating point rounding differences.

Comment: Thank you both for the changes and the info!

Comment: Yeah, thx. I noticed some problems with sort, before I applied the on-argument so that was also an improvment

Answer (score 1):

Using the given example, another option is the 'dplyr' package.

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- data.frame(A1 = c(1,2,3), A2 = c("A", "B", "D"))
df2 <- data.frame(A1 = c(3,2,3), A2 = c("A", "B", "C"))

inner_join(df1, df2)
```

Comment: sorry, I did not read 'data.table' in the title ... ;-), but dplyr works for data.table(s) as well

Comment: No problem -  I had planned to use just that if there hadn't been a dt solution :)