# ifelse assignment in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I am a teacher, and would like to correctly use the `data.table` package in `R` to automatically grade student answers in a log file, i.e. add a column called `correct` if the student answer to a particular question, is the correct answer to that question, and 0 otherwise. I can do this easily if each question has only 1 answer, but I am getting tripped up if a question has multiple possible answers (questions and their possible correct answers are stored in another table)

Below is a MWE:

```
set.seed(123)
question_table <- data.table(id=c(1,1,2,2,3,4),correct_ans=sample(1:4,6,replace = T))
log <- data.table(student=sample(letters[1:3],10,replace = T),
                  question_id=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4), 
                  student_answer= c(2,4,1,3,2,4,4,5,2,1))
```

My question lies in what is the correct `data.table` way to use `ifelse` in `j`, especially if we depend on another table?

```
log[,correct:=ifelse(student_answer %in% 
                          question_table[log$question_id %in% id]$correct_ans,1,0)]
```

As can be seen below, question 1 and 2 both have multiple possible correct answers.

```
> question_table
   id correct_ans
1:  1           2
2:  1           4
3:  2           2
4:  2           4
5:  3           4
6:  4           1
```

While the correct column is calculated without errors, something isn't right: e.g. when `student b` answers question, he is awarded a correct score, even though he answered incorrectly. Only some entries of the `correct` column are off, which leads me to believe there is something i am not getting with how variables have are scoped.

```
> log
    student question_id student_answer correct
 1:       b           1              2       1
 2:       c           1              4       1
 3:       b           1              1       1   <- ?
 4:       b           2              3       0
 5:       c           2              2       1
 6:       b           2              4       1
 7:       c           3              4       1
 8:       b           3              5       0
 9:       a           4              2       1   <- ?
10:       c           4              1       1
```

I considered making a helper column with the correct ans in the `log` table by `join`ing with `question_table`, but that does not work since the key is not unique in the latter.

Any and all help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a join:

```
# initialize to zero
log[, correct := 0L ]

# update to 1 if matched
log[question_table, on=c(question_id = "id", student_answer = "correct_ans"),
   correct := 1L ] 

    student question_id student_answer correct
 1:       b           1              2       1
 2:       c           1              4       1
 3:       b           1              1       0
 4:       b           2              3       0
 5:       c           2              2       1
 6:       b           2              4       1
 7:       c           3              4       1
 8:       b           3              5       0
 9:       a           4              2       0
10:       c           4              1       1
```

*How it works.* The syntax for an update join is `X[Y, on=cols, xvar := z]`:

- If col names differ between `X` and `Y`, use `on=c(xcol = "ycol", xcol2 = "ycol2")` or, in version 1.9.7+, `.(xcol = ycol, xcol2 = ycol2)`.
- `xvar := z` will only operate on the rows of `X` that are matched. Sometimes, it is also useful to use `by=.EACHI` here, depending on how many rows of `X` are matched by each in `Y` and how complicated the expression for `z` is.

See `?data.table` for full documentation on the syntax.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply! Might you be able to explain the syntax? I have read [this](https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/52230_5ae0d25125b544caab32f75f0360e775.html) post in `join` in `data.table` several times, but still do not see how your answer, links to the ideas of keys, nor the `i`,`j`,`by`, `:=` notation. Or at least point me to some other documentation that would explain the reasoning?

Comment: @Sameer Good question. The official vignette on joins is not out yet, you can track it along with other new docs here: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/944 The currently released vignettes and FAQ are here: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started In the meantime, I have some notes here: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/data.table/4976/joins-and-merges#t=201610291315481350706 The blog you linked is out of date and keys are rarely needed now, as Arun explains: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20057411/

Comment: vignettes is not out but manual covers that very well, including examples, see [?data.table](http://jangorecki.gitlab.io/data.table/library/data.table/html/data.table.html)