# Match multiple columns in one data frame to either of two data frames on multiple criteria

Tags: r, conditional-statements, match

In this toy example (which in reality is big data) I have a data frame with personal records which I need to look matches for in two databases.

```
df <- structure(list(FORENAME = c("GUY", "JULIANA", "BENN"), SURNAME = c("WEEKS", 
"BAIN", "SARAH"), DOB = c("07/01/1985", "20/06/1967", "04/09/1985"
)), .Names = c("FORENAME", "SURNAME", "DOB"), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = "data.frame")

> df
  FORENAME SURNAME        DOB
1      GUY   WEEKS 07/01/1985
2  JULIANA    BAIN 20/06/1967
3     BENN   SARAH 04/09/1985
```

Database 1

```
db1 structure(list(FORENAME = c("GUY", "SARAH", "REBECCA"), SURNAME = c("WEEKS", 
"BENN", "SYMES"), DOB = c("07/01/1985", "04/09/1985", "10/07/1990"
)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("FORENAME", 
"SURNAME", "DOB"))

> db1
  FORENAME SURNAME        DOB
1      GUY   WEEKS 07/01/1985
2    SARAH    BENN 04/09/1985
3  REBECCA   SYMES 10/07/1990
```

Database 2

```
db2 <- structure(list(FORENAME = c("NAILA", "JOANNE", "JULIANA"), SURNAME = c("KHAN", 
"WHITEHEAD", "BAIN"), DOB = c("06/01/1957", "24/08/1970", "20/06/1967"
)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("FORENAME", 
"SURNAME", "DOB"))

> db2
  FORENAME   SURNAME        DOB
1    NAILA      KHAN 06/01/1957
2   JOANNE WHITEHEAD 24/08/1970
3  JULIANA      BAIN 20/06/1967
```

For the sake of example, I am looking to apply two matching criteria:

1. All three fields equal
2. FOREMNAME = SURNAME, SURNAME=FORENAME, DOB=DOB (to capture cases which switched the order of names)

...and look for matches in either database, so something like:

```
((df1$FORENAME == db1$FORENAME | db2$FORENAME) & 
(df1$SURNAME == db1$SURNAME | db2$SURNAME) &
(df1$DOB == db1$DOB | db2$DOB))
|
((df1$FORENAME == db1$SURNAME | db2$SURNAME) &
(df1$SURNAME ==db1$FORENAME | db2$FORENAME) &
(df1$DOB == db1$DOB | db2$DOB))
```

I want to keep the original `df` intact and am looking to create a columnt for the result like so:

```
  FORENAME SURNAME        DOB RESULT
1      GUY   WEEKS 07/01/1985  MATCH
2  JULIANA    BAIN 20/06/1967  MATCH
3     BENN   SARAH 04/09/1985  MATCH
```

What would be an elegnt way to do it, assuming the real data is hundreds of thousands of rows long, and will involve matching on c. 8 columns and c. 15 criteria?

As this does not require any fuzzy-matching, an unelegant solution that I can think of would be to do a series of `dplyr`'s `inner_join`s followed by `rbind` of everything into one big table and `unique(df_matched)`. Then `left_join(df, df_matched, by=c(...list of columns))` in order to create the `RESULT` column in the original `df`.

Comment: Something along these lines might work: http://stackoverflow.com/q/40314562/