# Find matches to several tables: conditional (full) join using data.table

Tags: r, join, data.table, left-join, match

This might have an easy solution, but I can't seem to crack it.

For an example, suppose I have a table listing purchases and customer details:

```
library(data.table)
purchase <- setDT(structure(list(Name = c("John", "John", "Mary"), Surname = c("Smith", 
"Smith", "Jane"), PurchaseDate = c("2017-01-01", "2015-01-01", 
"2017-01-02")), .Names = c("Name", "Surname", "PurchaseDate"), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame")))

> purchase
   Name Surname PurchaseDate
1: John   Smith   2017-01-01
2: John   Smith   2015-01-01
3: Mary    Jane   2017-01-02
```

And I want to find if these customers held a valid discount card at a time of purchase, which matches data held in two databases:

```
df1 <- setDT(structure(list(Name = "John", Surname = "Smith", ValidFrom = "2016-12-31", 
    ValidTo = "2017-01-02"), .Names = c("Name", "Surname", "ValidFrom", 
"ValidTo"), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame")))

df2 <- setDT(structure(list(Name = "Mary", Surname = "Jane", ValidFrom = "2017-01-01", 
    ValidTo = "2017-01-03"), .Names = c("Name", "Surname", "ValidFrom", 
"ValidTo"), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame")))

> df1
   Name Surname  ValidFrom    ValidTo
1: John   Smith 2016-12-31 2017-01-02
> df2
   Name Surname  ValidFrom    ValidTo
1: Mary    Jane 2017-01-01 2017-01-03
```

I am adapting [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40314562/) solution, which uses `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
purchase[df1, on=c(Name='Name', Surname='Surname'), Match := 'Yes']
purchase[df2, on=c(Name='Name', Surname='Surname'), Match := 'Yes']
```

The results of this (based on left join) are saved to the `Match` variable in the original `purchase` table. (Importantly, this does not require creating a new object, but saves the result to the original object, otherwise it would become messy.)

```
> purchase
   Name Surname PurchaseDate Match
1: John   Smith   2017-01-01   Yes
2: John   Smith   2015-01-01   Yes
3: Mary    Jane   2017-01-02   Yes
```

But, I also need to check that the `PurchaseDate` is within `ValidFrom` and `ValidTo` dates, and don't have a good idea of how to do this.

To do this, I can bring in the `ValidFrom` and `ValidTo` dates to the join and later determine whether the purchase was between those dates using `ifelse`.

```
purchase[df1, on=c(Name='Name', Surname='Surname'), `:=`(Match='Yes', VFrom=ValidFrom, VTo=ValidTo)]
purchase[df2, on=c(Name='Name', Surname='Surname'), `:=`(Match='Yes', VFrom=ValidFrom, VTo=ValidTo)]
```

Great! This brings the dates:

```
   Name Surname PurchaseDate Match      VFrom        VTo
1: John   Smith   2017-01-01   Yes 2016-12-31 2017-01-02
2: John   Smith   2015-01-01   Yes 2016-12-31 2017-01-02
3: Mary    Jane   2017-01-02   Yes 2017-01-01 2017-01-03
```

But, the problem arises if customer had two discount cards, and a purchase falls in the period of validity of only one of them. Suppose Mary had two cards:

```
df2 <- setDT(structure(list(Name = structure(c(1L, 1L), .Label = "Mary", class = "factor"), 
    Surname = structure(c(1L, 1L), .Label = "Jane", class = "factor"), 
    ValidFrom = structure(1:2, .Label = c("2017-01-01", "1945-01-01"
    ), class = "factor"), ValidTo = structure(1:2, .Label = c("2017-01-03", 
    "1946-01-01"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Name", "Surname", 
"ValidFrom", "ValidTo"), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame")))

> df2
   Name Surname  ValidFrom    ValidTo
1: Mary    Jane 2017-01-01 2017-01-03
2: Mary    Jane 1945-01-01 1946-01-01
```

Running this

```
purchase[df2, on=c(Name='Name', Surname='Surname'), `:=`(Match='Yes', VFrom=ValidFrom, VTo=ValidTo)]
```

Brings only one of these pairs of dates (apparently the earlies one, regardless of the row number).

```
   Name Surname PurchaseDate Match      VFrom        VTo
1: John   Smith   2017-01-01   Yes 2016-12-31 2017-01-02
2: John   Smith   2015-01-01   Yes 2016-12-31 2017-01-02
3: Mary    Jane   2017-01-02   Yes 1945-01-01 1946-01-01
```

How would I bring in all matched rows?

From what I learned, `X[Y]` syntax supports appending to the original object (which I need), and also the `:=` function, which I need, but does not support a full join. An alternative `merge` supports full joins, but requires creation of new object at every join-step (will be extremely messy), and does not support `:=`. Any ideas? Is there a way to use `foverlaps` somehow?

Comment: Any good reason for not combining df1 and df2 into a single table? Also, I'm not sure what your desired output is. To bring in all the rows, do you mean to increase the number of rows in `purchase`? If you just want `Match`, it's a lot simpler; you could look up "non equi join".

Comment: @Frank df1/df2 historically hold data for two different types, but may be possible to combine them. But even if combined, still can't use `merge` syntax with assigning things to new object, because will use many combinations of match, e.g. `c(name, surname, address)`, then `c(dob, name, surname)`, them `c(dob, postcode)` etc...

Comment: @Frank you are right, desired output is to add rows to `purchase` (if matched). I then have an idea of how to filter it to at least one positive match with a valid date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way of approaching it:

```
# clean data
purchase[, PurchaseDate := as.IDate(PurchaseDate)]
df1[, `:=`(ValidFrom = as.IDate(ValidFrom), ValidTo = as.IDate(ValidTo))]
df2[, `:=`(ValidFrom = as.IDate(ValidFrom), ValidTo = as.IDate(ValidTo))]

# initialize
purchase[, matched := FALSE ]

# update joins
purchase[!(matched), matched := 
  df1[.SD, on=.(Name, Surname, ValidFrom <= PurchaseDate, ValidTo >= PurchaseDate), 
    .N, by=.EACHI ]$N > 0L
]
purchase[!(matched), matched := 
  df2[.SD, on=.(Name, Surname, ValidFrom <= PurchaseDate, ValidTo >= PurchaseDate), 
    .N, by=.EACHI ]$N > 0L
]
```

I'm keeping `df1` and `df2` separate since the OP mentioned that their join rules differ in their actual use-case.

---

*How it works*

The overall structure is...

```
DT[, matched := FALSE ]
DT[!(matched), matched := expr1 ]
DT[!(matched), matched := expr2 ]
```

so we're initializing `matched` to false; and at each later step, updating unmatched rows, `!(matched)`.

The expressions start with `DT2[.SD, ...]`, which is just a join against the Subset of Data we have after filtering with `!(matched)`. Joins like this look up rows of `.SD` in `DT2` according to the `on=` filters. In this case, the `on=` filters are associated with a non equi join.`***`

When we use `by=.EACHI` we are grouping by each row of `.SD`. With `.N, by=.EACHI`, we get the number of `DT2` rows matched for each row of `.SD`.

Once we have the number of matched rows, we can compare `N > 0L` to update `matched`.

---

`***` Unfortunately, as of April 2017 [there's an open bug](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1926) in this pattern of usage that sometimes gives an error about `.SD`. The workaround is to replace `.SD` with `copy(.SD)`.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you! I should really make an effort learning `data.table`. Would you mind explaining how the actual matching line works step by step in detail?

Comment: Small problem: matching to `df1` works fine, following this by matching to `df2` gives error. `Error in set(origi, j = lc, value = factor(origi[[lc]])) : 
  .SD is locked. Updating .SD by reference using := or set are reserved for future use. Use := in j directly. Or use copy(.SD) as a (slow) last resort, until shallow() is exported.`

Comment: @Mihael Yeah, in that case, I think editing .SD to copy(.SD) per the error message is a necessary workaround. It's a known bug, but I'm not really sure when it's triggered: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1926 You could try updating to the "devel" version of the package where it might be less often triggered (though I'm not sure). I'm adding an explanation now, btw.

Comment: as you've helpfully answered this question awhile ago, I would be grateful if you could have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45212781/unexpected-behaviour-in-data-table-non-equi-join) question as well. It follows from your solution and there appears to be some buggy behaviour. Perhaps you may have some ideas. @Frank