# Unexpected behaviour in data.table non-equi join

Tags: r, join, data.table, left-join, match

This is a follow-up on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43660562/find-matches-to-several-tables-conditional-full-join-using-data-table) question, where the accepted answer showed an example of a matching exercise using `data.table`, including non-equi conditions.

**Background**

The basic set up is that we have `DT1` with a sample of people's details, and `DT2`, which is a sort-of master database. And the aim is to find out whether each person in `DT1` matches at least one entry in `DT2`.

First, we initialize a column that would indicate a match to `FALSE`, so that its values could be updated to `TRUE` whenever a match is found.

```
DT1[, MATCHED := FALSE]
```

The following general solution is then used to update the column:

```
DT1[, MATCHED := DT2[.SD, on=.(Criteria), .N, by=.EACHI ]$N > 0L ]
```

In theory, it looks (and should work) fine. The sub-expression `DT2[.SD, on=.(Criteria), .N, by=.EACHI]` produces a sub-table with each row from `DT1`, and computes the `N` column which is the number of matches for that row found in `DT2`. Then, whenever `N` is greater than zero, the value of `MATCHED` in `DT1` is updated to `TRUE`.

It works as intended in a trivial [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43660562/find-matches-to-several-tables-conditional-full-join-using-data-table). But I encountered some unexpected behaviour using it with the real data, and cannot get to the bottom of it. I may be missing something or it may be a bug. Unfortunately, I cannot provide a minimal reproducible example, because the data is big, and it only shows in the big data. But I will try to document it as best I can.

**Unexpected behaviour or a bug**

What helped noticing this is that, for a historic reason, the matches needed to be sought in two separate databases, and hence, the filter `!(MATCHED)` was added to the expression to update only those values which have not already been matched:

```
DT1[!(MATCHED), MATCHED := DT2[.SD, on=.(Criteria), .N, by=.EACHI ]$N > 0L ]
```

I then noticed that if the line is re-ran several times, with each subsequent run, there will be more and more matches, which were not matched in the preceding runs. (Nothing to do with separate databases, each run matches to DT2).

First run:

```
   MATCHED       N
1:   FALSE 3248007
2:    TRUE 2379514
```

Second run:

```
   MATCHED       N
1:   FALSE 2149648
2:    TRUE 3477873
```

To investigate, I then filtered cases which weren't matched on the first run, but were matched on the second. It looks like most cases were false negatives, i.e. those which should have been matched on the first run, but weren't. (But with many runs, eventually there appear also many false positives).

For example, here is one entry from `DT1`:

```
         DATE FORENAME SURNAME
1: 2016-01-01     JOHN   SMITH
```

And a matching entry from DT2:

```
   START_DATE EXPIRY_DATE FORENAME SURNAME
1: 2015-09-09  2017-05-01     JOHN   SMITH
```

Running the sub-expression (described above) alone, outside the main expression, to look at the `N` numbers, we see that it does not result in a match, when it should (`N=0`). (You may also note that `START_DATE` and `END_DATE` take on the value of `DATE` in the output, but that is a whole other issue).

```
SUB <- DF2[DF1, on=.(FORENAME, SURNAME, START_DATE <= DATE, EXPIRY_DATE >= DATE), .N, by=.EACHI]
SUB[FORENAME=="JOHN" & "SURNAME=="SMITH"]

   FORENAME SURNAME START_DATE EXPIRY_DATE N
1:     JOHN   SMITH 2016-01-01  2016-01-01 0
```

However, the buggy behaviour is that the result is affected by what other rows are present in `DF1`. For example, suppose I know that `JOHN SMITH`'s row number in `DF1` is 149 and filter `DF1` to only that row:

```
DF2[DF1[149], on=.(FORENAME, SURNAME, START_DATE <= DATE, EXPIRY_DATE >= DATE), .N, by=.EACHI]

   FORENAME SURNAME START_DATE EXPIRY_DATE N
1:     JOHN   SMITH 2016-01-01  2016-01-01 1
```

Secondly, I also noticed that the buggy behaviour occurs only with more than one non-equi criterion in the conditions. If the conditions are `on=.(FORENAME, SURNAME, START_DATE <= DATE)`, there are no longer any differences between the runs and all rows appear to be matched correctly the first time.

Unfortunately, to solve the real-world problem, I **must** have several non-equi matching conditions. Not only to ensure that `DT1`'s `DATE` is between `DT2`'s `START_DATE` and `END_DATE`s, but also that `DT1`'s `CHECKING_DATE` is before `DT2`'s `EFFECTIVE_DATE`, etc.

**To summarize**

Non-equi joins in `data.table` behave in a buggy way when:

1. Some rows are present/absent from one of the tables

AND

2. More than one non-equi conditions

**Update: Reproducible example**

```
set.seed(123)
library(data.table)
library(stringi)

n <- 100000

DT1 <- data.table(RANDOM_STRING = stri_rand_strings(n, 5, pattern = "[a-k]"),
                  DATE = sample(seq(as.Date('2016-01-01'), as.Date('2016-12-31'), by="day"), n, replace=T))

DT2 <- data.table(RANDOM_STRING = stri_rand_strings(n, 5, pattern = "[a-k]"),
                  START_DATE = sample(seq(as.Date('2015-01-01'), as.Date('2017-12-31'), by="day"), n, replace=T))

DT2[, EXPIRY_DATE := START_DATE + floor(runif(1000, 200,300))]

#Initialization
DT1[, MATCHED := FALSE]

#First run
DT1[!(MATCHED), MATCHED := DT2[.SD, on=.(RANDOM_STRING, START_DATE <= DATE, EXPIRY_DATE >= DATE), .N, by=.EACHI ]$N > 0L ]
DT1[, .N, by=MATCHED]

   MATCHED     N
1:   FALSE 85833
2:    TRUE 14167

#Second run
DT1[!(MATCHED), MATCHED := DT2[.SD, on=.(RANDOM_STRING, START_DATE <= DATE, EXPIRY_DATE >= DATE), .N, by=.EACHI ]$N > 0L ]
DT1[, .N, by=MATCHED]

   MATCHED     N
1:   FALSE 73733
2:    TRUE 26267

#And so on with subsequent runs...
```

Comment: Uh oh, this is interesting/useful to me, since I use the `.N, by=.EACHI]$N > 0` idiom all the time myself. As you say, when only the relevant rows are present it gives the right result (my repro is here: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25312/r-public ). It'd be great if you could come up with a reproducible example.

Comment: @Frank, see if you can replicate it on some of your own data by re-running the matching statement repeatedly, but each time with a `!(MATCHED)` filter, so the input is different each time, like I described in the post. In the meantime, I'll see if I can come up with a reproducible example. The problem is, I've only seen it occur when there are thousands of rows, and all my data are personal confidential details.

Comment: @Mihael what is the order of magnitude of rows/columns you are talking about, when this incident takes place?

Comment: @Frank, I've edited my post by adding a reproducible example at the end.

Comment: @amonk, see the reproducible example I've added to the post.

Comment: @Frank: added `set.seed()` and updated the outputs.

Comment: Thanks, okay so an example is row `w = 71`: when subsetting we have the right answer `DT1[w, DT2[.SD, on=.(RANDOM_STRING, START_DATE <= DATE, EXPIRY_DATE >= DATE), .N, by=.EACHI ]$N > 0L ]` but if we subset "afterwards", we get the wrong answer `DT1[, DT2[.SD, on=.(RANDOM_STRING, START_DATE <= DATE, EXPIRY_DATE >= DATE), .N, by=.EACHI ]$N > 0L ][w]`. Code for finding this... https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/38239131#38239131

Comment: Filed an issue with the package: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/2275 (forgot to link it earlier)

Comment: The issue linked in the last comment is fixed and closed on the devel branch of the package now. I guess it will be available on CRAN for 1.10.6

Answer (score 1):

This is a workaround solution, which is not at all elegant, but appears to give the right result while the bug is not fixed.

First, we need each row in `DT1` and `DT2` to have a unique id. A row number will do.

```
DT1[, DT1_ID := 1:nrow(DT1)]
DT2[, DT2_ID := 1:nrow(DT2)]
```

Then, we do a following right join to find the matches:

```
M <- DT2[DT1, on=.(RANDOM_STRING, START_DATE <= DATE, EXPIRY_DATE >= DATE)]

head(M, 3)

   RANDOM_STRING START_DATE EXPIRY_DATE DT2_ID DT1_ID
1:         diejk 2016-03-30  2016-03-30     NA      1
2:         afjgf 2016-09-14  2016-09-14     NA      2
3:         kehgb 2016-12-11  2016-12-11     NA      3
```

`M` has each row from `DT1` next to all matches for that row in `DT2`. When `DT2_ID = NA`, there was no match. `nrow(M) = 100969`, indicating that some `DT1` rows were matched to >1 `DT2` row. (Dates also took on the wrong values.)

Next, we can use an `ifelse()` statement to label rows in the original `DT1` according to whether or not they were matched.

```
DT1$MATCHED <- ifelse(DT1$DT1_ID %in% M[!is.na(DT2_ID)]$DT1_ID, TRUE, FALSE)
```

Final result: 13,316 matches of 100,000

```
DT1[, .N, by=MATCHED]

   MATCHED     N
1:   FALSE 86684
2:    TRUE 13316
```

Comment: Looks good, but fyi, you can use `.I` instead of `1:nrow(DT)` and `cond` instead of `ifelse(cond, TRUE, FALSE)`.

Comment: A somewhat simpler variation is: `w = DT1[DT2, on=.(RANDOM_STRING, DATE >= START_DATE, DATE <= EXPIRY_DATE), which=TRUE, nomatch=0]; DT1[, m := DT1_ID %in% w ]`. This works because nomatch=0 drops the unmatched/NA cases and which=TRUE returns only row numbers of DT1.