# How to deal with join keys of a different length and variable ordering?

Tags: r, data.table

Consider two data tables where the number of key columns differ:

```
library(data.table)
tmp_dt <- data.table(group1 = letters[1:5], group2 = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2), a = rnorm(5), key = c("group1", "group2"))
tmp_dt2 <- data.table(group2 = c(1, 2, 3), color = c("r", "g", "b"), key = "group2")
```

I want to join `tmp_dt` to `tmp_dt2` by `group2`, however the following fails:

```
tmp_dt[tmp_dt2]

> tmp_dt[tmp_dt2]
Error in bmerge(i, x, leftcols, rightcols, io, xo, roll, rollends, nomatch,  : 
  x.'group1' is a character column being joined to i.'group2' which is type 'double'. Character columns must join to factor or character columns.
```

This makes sense since it tries to join the data tables on the first key variable. How do I fix it so that the behaviour is the same as `dplyr::inner_join`, without incurring overheads in resetting the key on `tmp_dt` twice?

```
> inner_join(tmp_dt, tmp_dt2, by = "group2")
  group1 group2          a color
1      a      1  0.2501413     r
2      b      1  0.6182433     r
3      c      2 -0.1726235     g
4      d      2 -2.2239003     g
5      e      2 -1.2636144     g
```

Comment: `...key = c("group2","group1")`

Comment: yes, but the key (pardon the pun) is that I do not wish for my data table rows to be ordered in that order.

Comment: Don't set keys at all. The current idiom is to use the `on=` argument. Check the docs for `[.data.table`. Also maybe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20039335/what-is-the-purpose-of-setting-a-key-in-data-table

Comment: ah thanks, did not realised I could do that. Can `on = ` be used even in the presence of keys?

Comment: Yes, it can. In rare cases, I guess there are still efficiency benefits from keying; but I mostly just use it for tables I will be manually joining on many times.

Comment: or falling back to a more explicit function call, `merge(tmp_dt, tmp_dt2, by = "group2")` works as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `lapply`

```
tmp_dt[,color:=unlist(lapply(.BY, function(x) tmp_dt2[group2==x, color])), by=group2]
```

As pointed out by Frank in the comments, using `on`

```
tmp_dt[tmp_dt2, on="group2"]

tmp_dt2[tmp_dt, on="group2"]
```

Using `on` is roughly twice as fast as `lapply` using `.BY`. Although the first example returns a sixth row of `NA 3 NA b`

Answer (score 0):

You should use this code

```
tmp_dt2[tmp_dt, on = 'group2']
```