# Write multiple csv files based on filter applied in r

Tags: r, csv, for-loop, dataframe

This is my dataframe

```
df_temp=data.frame(ID=c(1,1,2,3,3),City=c("a","a","b","c","c"),Qty=c(20,14,40,50,60))
```

I want to filter the data for unique city and export that data based on the filtered result with the name as the name of unique city
so my that I'll have 3(a.csv, b.csv, c.csv) csv files with records

```
a.csv
ID  City Qty
1    a    20
1    a    14

b.csv
ID  City Qty
2    b    40

c.csv
ID  City Qty
3    c    50
3    c    60
```

This is what I have tried

```
name=as.character(unique(df_temp[,2]))
df_temp1=c()
for(i in df_temp[,2]){
paste("D:/Files",df_temp[i,2])
df_temp1[i]=filter(df_temp, City %in% c("a"))
write.csv("D/:Files",paste("D:/Files",name[i],".csv",sep = ""))
}
```

But That gives my "FileNa.csv" with empty rows.
Any help would be much appreciated..Thanks

Comment: first argument of `write.csv` is supposed to be the `R` object you want to write

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Check the correct arguments with `?write.csv`: `write.table(x, file = "")`.
2. If I do not misunderstand, the idea should be to create the data frames first without necessarily including their paths for the filenames.
3. I guess you want to cycle through the unique city names, and not for every city name in the `for()` loop.
4. Use well-formatted code in your next questions, please (with spaces -- you could also consult [Google's R Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/Rguide.xml)).
5. Why do you use `=` instead of `<-`? Why do you use `%in%` ? Why do you use `filter()` instead of `subset()`? 
   Please consult the relevant function documentations (e.g.: `?filter` shows that this is **not** an appropriate function for what you want to do!)

The following stores each dataframe as an element of a list, for each city name. 
It also saves a csv file for each data frame (each dataframe corresponds to a different city).

```
dataframe_temp = data.frame(ID = c(1, 1, 2, 3, 3), 
                            City = c("a", "a", "b", "c", "c"), 
                            Qty = c(20, 14, 40, 50, 60))

dataframe.list <- list()

# avoid hardcoded numbers as ", 2" as theses can 
# change in the future, after e.g. an expansion of the dataframe!
for (city in unique(dataframe_temp$City)) { 

    print(city)

    dataframe.list[[i]] = subset(dataframe_temp, City == city) 

    # use your folder location instead of "~/"
    write.csv(x = dataframe.list[[i]], file = paste0("~/", "dataframe_for_city_", city,".csv")) 
}
```

For net stumblers, I expand the answer of emilliman5 for larger (think of writing multi-GB a lot faster) datasets with `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(ID = c(1, 1, 2, 3, 3), 
                        City = c("a", "a", "b", "c", "c"), 
                        Qty = c(20, 14, 40, 50, 60))
# setkeyv(DT, 'City') # check if you really need a key: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20039335/what-is-the-purpose-of-setting-a-key-in-data-table
invisible(lapply(unique(DT[, City]), function(city) 
          fwrite(x = subset(DT, City == city), 
              file = paste0("~/", "DT_for_city_", city,".csv"))))
```

Comment: Yes This worked ..Thanks a ton ..Thanks for the effort!!!

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
df_temp=data.frame(ID=c(1,1,2,3,3),City=c("a","a","b","c","c"),Qty=c(20,14,40,50,60))

cities <- split(df_temp, df_temp$City)

lapply(cities, function(x) write.csv(x, file=paste0("D:/Files/City_", x[1,"City"], ".txt")))
```

Comment: please see my edit

Comment: yeah.. works perfectly fine ...Thanks ..Thanks for the effort!!!!