# Do `data.table` secondary indices have type limitations?

Tags: r, types, data.table

When a `data.table` secondary index is set on on a numeric vector, it does not seem to allow for subsetting rows using the `on =` syntax. However, I couldn't see anything in the documentation that would indicate that only character columns can be secondary indices. Is the `on =` syntax limited to character columns?

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(A = 1:10, B = letters[1:10])
setindex(dt, A, B)
dt[on = "B", "c"]
dt[on = "A", 3]
```

Comment: I can get `dt[on = "A", .(1)]` to work, along with `dt[on = "B", .("c")]` - not sure why character works when not in a list though.

Comment: That's a great idea! It does indeed work when putting the query in a list. On looking at the documentation, it seems the authors intend queries to be generally be wrapped in a list for secondary indexing. Feel free to submit your answer so I can accept it as correct

Comment: I will wait to see if some of the more data.table savvy folks pop around with an actual reason why one works and the other doesn't. I think you are right that the list is preferred, but this seems a little strange.

Comment: I should have looked at the "Keys and fast binary search" document more carefully; it says: "On single column key of character type, you can drop the `.()` notation and use the values directly when subsetting, like subset using row names on data.frames." This is a little unusual, since I have normally found indexing on key columns works without the `.()` syntax for numeric columns as well, but apparently this doesn't carry over into secondary indices.

Comment: Nice find, the good ol' manual comes into play again! I think you can answer your own question now to reap those internet points! :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `?data.table`:

> `i`
>
> `character`, `list` and `data.frame` input to `i` is converted into a `data.table` internally using `as.data.table`.

As a result, a join is done, either using a key or [just with `on=`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20057411/1191259).

The option to skip `.()` for character columns is also noted in the "Keys and fast binary search" vignette, `vignette("datatable-keys-fast-subset")`:

> On single column key of character type, you can drop the `.()` notation and use the values directly when subsetting, like subset using row names on data.frames.

Comment: Re the second half of your answer, this has nothing to do with keys or indices, it's just an interface design for `DT[...]`. If you pass numbers without `.()` they are interpreted as row numbers. If you pass a string without `.()`, it is interpreted as a join (allowing the `.()` to be skipped for convenience when typing, I guess). And if you pass a single symbol, it is also interpreted as a join.