# How to make continuous time sequences within groups in data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

I have a `data.table` containing time series of hourly observations from different locations (sites). There are gaps -- missing hours -- in each sequence. I want to fill out the sequence of hours for each site, so each sequence has a row for each hour (although data will be missing, NA).

Example data:

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)

DT <- data.table(site = rep(LETTERS[1:2], each = 3),
                 date = ymd_h(c("2017080101", "2017080103", "2017080105",
                                "2017080103", "2017080105", "2017080107")),
                 # x = c(1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3), 
                 x = c(1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3), 
                 key = c("site", "date"))
DT
#    site                date   x
# 1:    A 2017-08-01 01:00:00 1.1
# 2:    A 2017-08-01 03:00:00 1.2
# 3:    A 2017-08-01 05:00:00 1.3
# 4:    B 2017-08-01 03:00:00 2.1
# 5:    B 2017-08-01 05:00:00 2.2
# 6:    B 2017-08-01 07:00:00 2.3
```

The desired result `DT2` would contain all the hours between the first (minimum) date and the last (maximum) date for each site, with x missing where the new rows are inserted:

```
#    site                date   x
# 1:    A 2017-08-01 01:00:00 1.1
# 2:    A 2017-08-01 02:00:00  NA
# 3:    A 2017-08-01 03:00:00 1.2
# 4:    A 2017-08-01 04:00:00  NA
# 5:    A 2017-08-01 05:00:00 1.3
# 6:    B 2017-08-01 03:00:00 2.1
# 7:    B 2017-08-01 04:00:00  NA
# 8:    B 2017-08-01 05:00:00 2.2
# 9:    B 2017-08-01 06:00:00  NA
#10:    B 2017-08-01 07:00:00 2.3
```

I have tried to join `DT` with a date sequence constructed from `min(date)` and `max(date)`. This is in the right direction, but the date range is over all sites rather than for each individual site, the filled in rows have missing site, and the sort order (key) is wrong:

```
DT[.(seq(from = min(date), to = max(date), by = "hour")),
    .SD, on="date"]
#    site                date   x
# 1:    A 2017-08-01 01:00:00 1.1
# 2:   NA 2017-08-01 02:00:00  NA
# 3:    A 2017-08-01 03:00:00 1.2
# 4:    B 2017-08-01 03:00:00 2.1
# 5:   NA 2017-08-01 04:00:00  NA
# 6:    A 2017-08-01 05:00:00 1.3
# 7:    B 2017-08-01 05:00:00 2.2
# 8:   NA 2017-08-01 06:00:00  NA
# 9:    B 2017-08-01 07:00:00 2.3
```

So I naturally tried adding `by = site`:

```
DT[.(seq(from = min(date), to = max(date), by = "hour")),
   .SD, on="date", by=.(site)]
#    site                date   x
# 1:    A 2017-08-01 01:00:00 1.1
# 2:    A 2017-08-01 03:00:00 1.2
# 3:    A 2017-08-01 05:00:00 1.3
# 4:   NA                <NA>  NA
# 5:    B 2017-08-01 03:00:00 2.1
# 6:    B 2017-08-01 05:00:00 2.2
# 7:    B 2017-08-01 07:00:00 2.3
```

But this doesn't work either. Can anyone suggest the right `data.table` formulation to give the desired filled-out `DT2` shown above?

Comment: Re why it doesn't work: `DT[i,j,by]` is read "filter by `i`; group by `by`; then do `j`." You are trying to make grouped operations in `i`.

Comment: Thanks @Frank. I can see now that I needed to put the `seq()` in `j`, and then use the resulting `DT` in `i`.

Answer (score 3):

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)  
setDT(DT)
test <- DT[, .(date = seq(min(date), max(date), by = 'hour')), by = 
              'site']
DT <- merge(test, DT, by = c('site', 'date'), all.x = TRUE)


DT
    site                date   x
 1:    A 2017-08-01 01:00:00 1.1
 2:    A 2017-08-01 02:00:00  NA
 3:    A 2017-08-01 03:00:00 1.2
 4:    A 2017-08-01 04:00:00  NA
 5:    A 2017-08-01 05:00:00 1.3
 6:    B 2017-08-01 03:00:00 2.1
 7:    B 2017-08-01 04:00:00  NA
 8:    B 2017-08-01 05:00:00 2.2
 9:    B 2017-08-01 06:00:00  NA
10:    B 2017-08-01 07:00:00 2.3
```

Comment: More standard in data.table: `DT[test, on=names(test)]`

Comment: @Frank Yes, you are right , sorry for that , i am not quit
Familiar with `data.table` :)

Comment: Thanks @Wen. Good answer. But I prefer having the `merge()` done with the `data.table` join syntax, which can take advantage of `data.table`s optimizatons (if any).

Comment: @DouglasClark Yes, you can using `join` instead of `merge`~ :)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to both Frank and Wen for putting me on the right track. I found a compact `data.table` solution. The result `DT2` is also keyed on site and date, as in the input table (which is desirable although I didn't request this in the OP). This is a reformulation of Wen's solution, in `data.table` syntax, which I assume will be slightly more efficient on large datasets.

```
DT2 <- DT[setkey(DT[, .(date = seq(from = min(date), to = max(date), 
                         by = "hour")), by = site], site, date), ]
DT2
#    site                date   x
# 1:    A 2017-08-01 01:00:00 1.1
# 2:    A 2017-08-01 02:00:00  NA
# 3:    A 2017-08-01 03:00:00 1.2
# 4:    A 2017-08-01 04:00:00  NA
# 5:    A 2017-08-01 05:00:00 1.3
# 6:    B 2017-08-01 03:00:00 2.1
# 7:    B 2017-08-01 04:00:00  NA
# 8:    B 2017-08-01 05:00:00 2.2
# 9:    B 2017-08-01 06:00:00  NA
#10:    B 2017-08-01 07:00:00 2.3
key(DT2)
# [1] "site" "date"
```

EDIT1: As mentioned by Frank, the `on=` syntax can also be used. The following `DT3` formulation gives the correct answer, but `DT3` is not keyed, while the `DT2` result is keyed. That means an 'extra' `setkey()` would be needed if a keyed result was desired.

```
DT3 <- DT[DT[, .(date = seq(from = min(date), to = max(date), 
                  by = "hour")), by = site], on = c("site", "date"), ]
DT3
#    site                date   x
# 1:    A 2017-08-01 01:00:00 1.1
# 2:    A 2017-08-01 02:00:00  NA
# 3:    A 2017-08-01 03:00:00 1.2
# 4:    A 2017-08-01 04:00:00  NA
# 5:    A 2017-08-01 05:00:00 1.3
# 6:    B 2017-08-01 03:00:00 2.1
# 7:    B 2017-08-01 04:00:00  NA
# 8:    B 2017-08-01 05:00:00 2.2
# 9:    B 2017-08-01 06:00:00  NA
#10:    B 2017-08-01 07:00:00 2.3
key(DT3)
# NULL
all.equal(DT2, DT3)
# [1] "Datasets has different keys. 'target': site, date. 'current' has no key."
all.equal(DT2, DT3, check.attributes = FALSE)
# [1] TRUE
```

Is there a way to write the `DT3` expression to give a keyed result, other than expressly using `setkey()`?

EDIT2: Frank's comment suggests an additional formulation `DT4` using `keyby = .EACHI`. In this case `.SD` is inserted as `j`, which is required when `by` or `keyby` is used. This gives the correct answer and the result is keyed like the `DT2` formulation.

```
DT4 <- DT[DT[, .(date = seq(from = min(date), to = max(date), by = "hour")), 
             by = site], on = c("site", "date"), .SD, keyby = .EACHI]
DT4
#    site                date   x
# 1:    A 2017-08-01 01:00:00 1.1
# 2:    A 2017-08-01 02:00:00  NA
# 3:    A 2017-08-01 03:00:00 1.2
# 4:    A 2017-08-01 04:00:00  NA
# 5:    A 2017-08-01 05:00:00 1.3
# 6:    B 2017-08-01 03:00:00 2.1
# 7:    B 2017-08-01 04:00:00  NA
# 8:    B 2017-08-01 05:00:00 2.2
# 9:    B 2017-08-01 06:00:00  NA
#10:    B 2017-08-01 07:00:00 2.3
key(DT4)
# [1] "site" "date"
identical(DT2, DT4)
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Looks good. Fyi, `on=` is now idiomatic instead of setting a key, for reasons explained by Arun here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20057411/

Comment: @Frank, I also got the correct answer using `on=` but the result wasn't keyed. So I kept the `setkey()` approach.

Comment: One crude way to make them match: replace `, ]` with `, .SD, keyby=.EACHI]`. If you have a good reason for wanting a key in this case, maybe make the case for a `keyon=` argument (or something) on the mailing list or issue tracker.