# Carry forward a specific value if observations stop before a certain time

Tags: r, data.table

For a longitudinal dataset, I want to carry forward observations that terminated before day 7 with y=3, completing records with consecutive days up until day 7 with y=3.  A related question is at [How to make continuous time sequences within groups in data.table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46202908) .   The following solution works but I would like to also have a solution that (1) subsetted the observations earlier (see below) or that (2) did the carry forward with a join in one step.

```
d <- data.table(t =c(1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6),
                id=c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5),
                y =c(1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3),
                x =c(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
                key=c('id', 't'))
d

    t id y x
 1: 1  1 1 0
 2: 2  1 2 0
 3: 1  2 1 1
 4: 2  2 2 1
 5: 3  2 3 1
 6: 1  3 1 0
 7: 2  3 1 0
 8: 1  4 1 1
 9: 2  4 2 1
10: 3  4 2 1
11: 5  4 3 1
12: 6  4 3 1
13: 7  4 3 1
14: 1  5 1 0
15: 2  5 2 0
16: 3  5 2 0
17: 5  5 2 0
18: 6  5 3 0

w <- d[, .(tlast=t, last3 = t == max(t) & y == 3 & t < 7, x=x), by=id]
w <- w[last3 == TRUE, .(t = (tlast + 1) : 7, y=rep(3, 7 - tlast), x=x), by=id]
d <- rbind(d, w)
setkey(d, id, t)
d

   t id y x
 1: 1  1 1 0
 2: 2  1 2 0
 3: 1  2 1 1
 4: 2  2 2 1
 5: 3  2 3 1
 6: 4  2 3 1
 7: 5  2 3 1
 8: 6  2 3 1
 9: 7  2 3 1
10: 1  3 1 0
11: 2  3 1 0
12: 1  4 1 1
13: 2  4 2 1
14: 3  4 2 1
15: 5  4 3 1
16: 6  4 3 1
17: 7  4 3 1
18: 1  5 1 0
19: 2  5 2 0
20: 3  5 2 0
21: 5  5 2 0
22: 6  5 3 0
23: 7  5 3 0
    t id y x
```

The following doesn't work (results in data.table with 0 rows and 4 cols)

```
w <- d[(t == max(t) & y == 3 & t < 7) == TRUE, .SD, by=id]
```

Comment: Hi Prof, in `data.table`, the order of operation is `i` then for each `by`, compute `j` and within each `by`, `.SD` contains the current subset of data (see Take DT, subset/reorder rows using `i`, then calculate `j`, grouped by `by` in https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.html). In the example data, there are no rows where `t == max(t) & y == 3 & t < 7` since `max(t)` is 7.

Comment: Thanks - it was the order of operations that I was forgetting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### data.table

```r
cols <- c("x", "y")
merge(d[, .(t = if (3 %in% y && max(t) < 7) as.numeric(c(t, (1+max(t)):7)) else t),
      by = .(id)], d, by = c("id", "t"), all.x = TRUE
  )[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, nafill, type = "locf"), by = .(id), .SDcols = cols][]
#        id     t     y     x
#     <num> <num> <num> <num>
#  1:     1     1     1     0
#  2:     1     2     2     0
#  3:     2     1     1     1
#  4:     2     2     2     1
#  5:     2     3     3     1
#  6:     2     4     3     1
#  7:     2     5     3     1
#  8:     2     6     3     1
#  9:     2     7     3     1
# 10:     3     1     1     0
# 11:     3     2     1     0
# 12:     4     1     1     1
# 13:     4     2     2     1
# 14:     4     3     2     1
# 15:     4     5     3     1
# 16:     4     6     3     1
# 17:     4     7     3     1
# 18:     5     1     1     0
# 19:     5     2     2     0
# 20:     5     3     2     0
# 21:     5     5     2     0
# 22:     5     6     3     0
# 23:     5     7     3     0
#        id     t     y     x
```

Walk-through:

- we first need to generate a list that contains the `t` values we need per-`id`, so

  ```r
  d[, .(t = if (3 %in% y && max(t) < 7) as.numeric(c(t, (1+max(t)):7)) else t), by = .(id)]
  #        id     t
  #     <num> <num>
  #  1:     1     1
  #  2:     1     2
  #  3:     2     1
  #  4:     2     2
  #  5:     2     3
  #  6:     2     4
  #  7:     2     5
  #  8:     2     6
  #  9:     2     7
  # 10:     3     1
  # 11:     3     2
  # 12:     4     1
  # 13:     4     2
  # 14:     4     3
  # 15:     4     5
  # 16:     4     6
  # 17:     4     7
  # 18:     5     1
  # 19:     5     2
  # 20:     5     3
  # 21:     5     5
  # 22:     5     6
  # 23:     5     7
  #        id     t
  ```

  This does not fill in missing steps (`4` is missing in `id`s 3 and 4). If `y` contains `3`, then we fill out `t` up to 7, otherwise we do nothing.

  **Note**: `t` here is `numeric`, which requires a little dancing with (`integer`) sequences, ergo the `as.numeric` to silence data.table's complaints about matching column types.
- a simple merge against the original `d` will leave some `NA` holes in the data, which is intentional:

  ```r
  merge(d[, .(t = if (3 %in% y && max(t) < 7) as.numeric(c(t, (1+max(t)):7)) else t), by = .(id)], d, by = c("id", "t"), all.x = TRUE)
  #        id     t     y     x
  #     <num> <num> <num> <num>
  #  1:     1     1     1     0
  #  2:     1     2     2     0
  #  3:     2     1     1     1
  #  4:     2     2     2     1
  #  5:     2     3     3     1
  #  6:     2     4    NA    NA
  #  7:     2     5    NA    NA
  #  8:     2     6    NA    NA
  #  9:     2     7    NA    NA
  # 10:     3     1     1     0
  # 11:     3     2     1     0
  # 12:     4     1     1     1
  # 13:     4     2     2     1
  # 14:     4     3     2     1
  # 15:     4     5     3     1
  # 16:     4     6     3     1
  # 17:     4     7     3     1
  # 18:     5     1     1     0
  # 19:     5     2     2     0
  # 20:     5     3     2     0
  # 21:     5     5     2     0
  # 22:     5     6     3     0
  # 23:     5     7    NA    NA
  #        id     t     y     x
  ```
- from here, it's as simple as `nafill(., type="locf")`, using `.SDcols` for efficiency (and generality, so that we don't care what other columns there are, as long as `cols` lists them).

---

The reason that

```r
d[(t == max(t) & y == 3 & t < 7) == TRUE, .SD, by=id]
```

returns 0 rows is that the `i` condition is *first* and not in `.SD`. Because of this, it is a global condition, not a per-group condition. The `by=` is not considered for the condition, so expression is equivalent to

```r
d[(t == max(t) & y == 3 & t < 7),] # no .SD, no by=
```

which is also 0 rows. But looking at it that way, realize that there is only one row where `t == max(t)`, row 13, where `t` is 7. On that row, `y` is 3 (so far so good), but `t<7` is not true.

Changing it to the per-group thing within `.SD` returns data:

```r
d[, .SD[(t == max(t) & y == 3 & t < 7),], by=id]
#       id     t     y     x
#    <num> <num> <num> <num>
# 1:     2     3     3     1
# 2:     5     6     3     0
```

Comment: Very nice!   If you would take a step back and assess your solution vs. my original `rbind` solution, in terms of understandability/elegance, I'd appreciate your perception.   Also can anyone shed light on why `w <- d[(t == max(t) & y == 3 & t < 7) == TRUE, .SD, by=id]
` doesn't work, and how to make it work?

Comment: I think conditions like that need to go on `.SD`, not in the global sense. Perhaps `d[,.SD[(t == max(t) & y == 3 & t < 7),], by=id]` is closer?

Comment: For me, part of the learning-curve of `data.table` is discovering that (typically) when there is a `by=`, anything in `i` should really be in `origdata[,.SD[i,],by=]`, not in `origdata[i,.SD,by=]`. I'm confident there are situations where this rule-of-thumb might not be best, but it's a start.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is more efficient, but here's a `dplyr` approach (my `data.table` knowledge is too limited for this one). Hopefully, you can adapt a `data.table` version of this if you find it useful.

```
library(dplyr)

crossing(id=unique(d$id), t=1:max(d$t)) %>% 
  full_join(d) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  filter(!(max(y, na.rm=TRUE) < 3 & is.na(y)) &
           !(is.na(y) & !is.na(lead(y)))) %>% 
  mutate(across(c(y,x), zoo::na.locf))
```

> ```
>       id     t     y     x
>  1     1     1     1     0
>  2     1     2     2     0
>  3     2     1     1     1
>  4     2     2     2     1
>  5     2     3     3     1
>  6     2     4     3     1
>  7     2     5     3     1
>  8     2     6     3     1
>  9     2     7     3     1
> 10     3     1     1     0
> 11     3     2     1     0
> 12     4     1     1     1
> 13     4     2     2     1
> 14     4     3     2     1
> 15     4     5     3     1
> 16     4     6     3     1
> 17     4     7     3     1
> 18     5     1     1     0
> 19     5     2     2     0
> 20     5     3     2     0
> 21     5     5     2     0
> 22     5     6     3     0
> 23     5     7     3     0
> ```

Comment: Thanks.  I'm seeking a `data.table` approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using `dplyr` this might do what you're looking for. Split the data set into two groups then address the cases that need the 3rd row repeated. `dplyr::summarize` is normally used to collapse many rows into one, but it can also expand one into many.

```
library(dplyr)

# original data
d <- tibble(t =c(1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6),
            id=c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5),
            y =c(1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3),
            x =c(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)) %>%
        arrange(id, t)


bind_rows(
    
    
    d %>%
        # subset for cases to leave alone
        group_by(id) %>%
        filter( max(t) < 3 | 7 <= max(t))  %>%
        ungroup(),
    
    d %>%
        # subset for cases to fill in by carrying values forward
        group_by(id) %>%
        filter(3 <= max(t) & max(t) < 7) %>%

        # get the 3rd row
        filter(t == 3) %>%

        # repeat 3rd row until there are 7 rows
        summarize(t = seq(t, 7), x = x, y = y)  %>%
        ungroup()
    
) %>% arrange(id, t)
```

Output

```
# A tibble: 20 x 4
       t    id     y     x
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1     1     1     0
 2     2     1     2     0
 3     3     2     3     1
 4     4     2     3     1
 5     5     2     3     1
 6     6     2     3     1
 7     7     2     3     1
 8     1     3     1     0
 9     2     3     1     0
10     1     4     1     1
11     2     4     2     1
12     3     4     2     1
13     5     4     3     1
14     6     4     3     1
15     7     4     3     1
16     3     5     2     0
17     4     5     2     0
18     5     5     2     0
19     6     5     2     0
20     7     5     2     0
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'm wanting a `data.table` approach.