# Join two datasets with closest timestamp interval

Tags: r, datatable, dplyr, timestamp

### I edited my question - please read the second part **Edit 2**

I need to join two dataset with the closet timestamp. The first datset is diary dataset from an mobile application:

```
    df1 <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
        datetime = c("2019-03-19T13:26:52Z", "2019-03-19T13:26:19Z",
                     "2019-03-19T13:23:46Z", "2019-03-19T13:22:20Z",
                     "2019-03-19T13:09:56Z", "2019-03-19T13:06:04Z", "2019-03-19T13:05:21Z",
                     "2019-03-19T13:04:37Z", "2019-03-19T12:47:28Z",
                     "2019-03-19T12:46:42Z"),
       transport = c("Trainride", "Trainride", "Trainride", "Trainride",
                     "Trainride", "Trainride", "Trainride", "Trainride",
                     "Trainride", "Trainride"),
              id = c("5-3", "5-3", "5-3", "5-3", "5-3", "5-3", "5-3", "5-3", "5-3",
                     "5-3"),
            disc = c("start", "stop", "start", "stop", "start", "stop", "start",
                     "stop", "start", "stop")
    )
 # datetime dttr object   
    df1 <- df1 %>% 
      mutate(datetime = lubridate::as_datetime(datetime))
```

here:

```
              datetime transport  id  disc
1  2019-03-19 13:26:52 Trainride 5-3 start
2  2019-03-19 13:26:19 Trainride 5-3  stop
3  2019-03-19 13:23:46 Trainride 5-3 start
4  2019-03-19 13:22:20 Trainride 5-3  stop
5  2019-03-19 13:09:56 Trainride 5-3 start
6  2019-03-19 13:06:04 Trainride 5-3  stop
7  2019-03-19 13:05:21 Trainride 5-3 start
8  2019-03-19 13:04:37 Trainride 5-3  stop
9  2019-03-19 12:47:28 Trainride 5-3 start
10 2019-03-19 12:46:42 Trainride 5-3  stop
```

and the second dataset is dataset from accelerometer log, showing movement(=INVH) or idle(=NIVH) :

```
df2 <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
           datetime = c("2019-03-19T23:20:00Z", "2019-03-19T23:17:30Z",
                        "2019-03-19T13:08:00Z", "2019-03-19T13:07:00Z",
                        "2019-03-19T12:38:45Z", "2019-03-19T12:32:45Z",
                        "2019-03-19T11:13:15Z", "2019-03-19T11:11:45Z", "2019-03-19T10:17:45Z",
                        "2019-03-19T10:16:45Z"),
                 id = c("5-3", "5-3", "5-3", "5-3", "5-3", "5-3", "5-3", "5-3", "5-3",
                        "5-3"),
               code = c("NIVH", "INVH", "NIVH", "INVH", "NIVH", "INVH", "NIVH",
                        "INVH", "NIVH", "INVH")
       )
 # datetime dttr object 
df2 <- df2 %>% 
  mutate(datetime = lubridate::as_datetime(datetime))
```

here:

```
              datetime  id code
1  2019-03-19 23:20:00 5-3 NIVH
2  2019-03-19 23:17:30 5-3 INVH
3  2019-03-19 13:08:00 5-3 NIVH
4  2019-03-19 13:07:00 5-3 INVH
5  2019-03-19 12:38:45 5-3 NIVH
6  2019-03-19 12:32:45 5-3 INVH
7  2019-03-19 11:13:15 5-3 NIVH
8  2019-03-19 11:11:45 5-3 INVH
9  2019-03-19 10:17:45 5-3 NIVH
10 2019-03-19 10:16:45 5-3 INVH
```

I need to join two data frames based on time difference between timestamp fields. for example left join on df1 to see how app diary data is an agreement with real accelerometer log. simple left join will not work here becuase in most of the case there is a lag time. So my questen is how can i join these two dataset 
based on the record where the difference is minimum absolute difference.

**EDIT 2 ---**
The solution suggested by @soren is helpful, however If I take start datetime and endtime to have a interval , will not work. any thought?

```
df1 <- df1 %>% 
  mutate(datetime = lubridate::as_datetime(datetime)) %>% 
  arrange(datetime) %>% 
  mutate(datetime_end = lead(datetime), 
         # Create an interval object.
         Travel_Interval = lubridate::interval(start = datetime, end = datetime_end))
```

Comment: what is the direction of the time lag? Is the timestamp in df2 always behind the timestamp in df1?

Comment: no, there is no logic actually , df2 can be behind or ahead by some minutes from df1

Answer (score 9):

A rolling join will accomplish this, joining the data frame by nearest datetime.  The following solution using data.table

```
library(data.table)
dt1 <- as.data.table(df1)
setkeyv(dt1,"datetime")

dt2 <- as.data.table(df2)
setkeyv(dt2,"datetime")
dt2[,nearest_date:=datetime]

dt2[dt1,roll="nearest"]

> dt2[dt1,roll="nearest"]
               datetime  id code        nearest_date transport i.id  disc
 1: 2019-03-19 12:46:42 5-3 NIVH 2019-03-19 12:38:45 Trainride  5-3  stop
 2: 2019-03-19 12:47:28 5-3 NIVH 2019-03-19 12:38:45 Trainride  5-3 start
 3: 2019-03-19 13:04:37 5-3 INVH 2019-03-19 13:07:00 Trainride  5-3  stop
 4: 2019-03-19 13:05:21 5-3 INVH 2019-03-19 13:07:00 Trainride  5-3 start
 5: 2019-03-19 13:06:04 5-3 INVH 2019-03-19 13:07:00 Trainride  5-3  stop
 6: 2019-03-19 13:09:56 5-3 NIVH 2019-03-19 13:08:00 Trainride  5-3 start
 7: 2019-03-19 13:22:20 5-3 NIVH 2019-03-19 13:08:00 Trainride  5-3  stop
 8: 2019-03-19 13:23:46 5-3 NIVH 2019-03-19 13:08:00 Trainride  5-3 start
 9: 2019-03-19 13:26:19 5-3 NIVH 2019-03-19 13:08:00 Trainride  5-3  stop
10: 2019-03-19 13:26:52 5-3 NIVH 2019-03-19 13:08:00 Trainride  5-3 start
```

Note that the additional column "nearest_date" is added `dt2[,nearest_date:=datetime]` so that when dt2 and dt1 are joined, the value of the datetime is retained (or available to use for difference calculations).  Whereas merging/joining datasets together by default return only the primary keyed column.  Normally, this is desirable since joined columns are frequently identical.  Here, with a rolling join they are not and it's useful to retain the column, or to manually create a redundant one, as is exemplified here.

Note also that nearest `id` value and `datetime` may also be relevant for the application (only one id value given in OP).  This is accomplished by setting the keys, which are used in the join syntax:

```
setkeyv(dt2,c("id","datetime"))
setkeyv(dt1,c("id","datetime"))
```

Comment: Fyi, `on=` is another option, recommended by the package authors towards the end of this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/20057411/

Comment: @Frank interesting article, thanks for the reference.  Worth noting that it there may be trade-offs in speed/efficiency in keyed vs ad-hoc joins for larger datasets and merit in playing around with either approach if application seeks absolute efficiency gains.

Comment: Thank you both. @Soren this is very helpful, yes the real data set has several ids and setting id and datetime as keys is what I need.